# Using parameters in inline script for Elasticsearch

Tags: python-2.7, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use Elasticsearch 5.1 inline script with parameters, however the params tag doesn't seems work:

Below query works without params:

```
{
  "query": {
  "match_all":{}
  },
  "script_fields": {
  "distance": {
    "script":{
    "lang":"painless",
     "inline":"doc['address_details.location.point'].arcDistance(-38.376465,144.829099)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below query doesn't work because I use params:

```
    {  
       "query":{  
          "match_all":{  

          }
       },
       "script_fields":{  
          "distance":{  
             "script":{  
                "lang":"painless",
                "inline":"doc['address_details.location.point'].arcDistance(latitude,longitude)",
                "params":{  
                   "latitude":-38.376465,
                   "longitude":144.829099
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

The error msg is : TransportError(500, u'search_phase_execution_exception', u'compile error')

I'm executing this query via python elasticsearch client, the client version I'm using is:
elasticsearch>=5.0.0,<6.0.0

The way I execute the query is:

```
conn=Elasticsearch(['http://username:password@localhost:9200/'])
conn.search(index='index_name',doc_type='type',body=query)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the Elasticsearch documentation is wrong, you should add "params." in front of the variables in order to access its values.

Here is the correct query:

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "match_all":{  

      }
   },
   "script_fields":{  
      "distance":{  
         "script":{  
            "lang":"painless",
            "inline":"doc['address_details.location.point'].arcDistance(params.latitude,params.longitude)",
            "params":{  
               "latitude":-38.376465,
               "longitude":144.829099
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see your 2nd query is invalid, you have mistake around `params`, you have `.arcDistance(latitude,longitude),"params"` to fix it just add `"` before comma, so `.arcDistance(latitude,longitude)","params"`

it should be like:

```
{  
   "query":{  
      "match_all":{  

      }
   },
   "script_fields":{  
      "distance":{  
         "script":{  
            "lang":"painless",
            "inline":"doc['address_details.location.point'].arcDistance(latitude,longitude)",
            "params":{  
               "latitude":-38.376465,
               "longitude":144.829099
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

The cleanly formatted code will fix most of these types of mistakes.

Comment: Hi AI-Mothafar, sorry it is my bad that I missed the quote when posting to the forum, my original query actually have the quote. I had modified my question accordingly with more details.